# Alexa SDK Android Sample code error

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am getting following error in Android Studio while trying to build the app:

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':aace'.

> executing external native build for cmake /home/user/Documents/aac-sdk-1.0/platforms/android/aace/CMakeLists.txt

I am have followed guldelines from below links:

https://github.com/alexa/avs-device-sdk/wiki/Ubuntu-Linux-Quick-Start-Guide

https://github.com/alexa/aac-sdk/blob/1.0/builder/BuildWithCMake.md

https://github.com/alexa/aac-sdk/tree/1.0/samples/android

Ubuntu 16.04 Android Studio 3.0.1, NDK 17.1 ,Android SDK Platform 26

Any help will be appreciated.